# Create Xbox Music Playlist from excel list (csv)

Tags: microsoft-excel, music, csv, playlists, xbox-music

I created a few playlists in Excel (just the artist & song title) that I wanted to Import into Xbox Music. Unfortunately the only way I could find was to search for each song indivdually and then add them to a playlist so I can listen to them with my Xbox Music Pass.

However this will take far too long as there are several hundred songs in those lists. Is there any way I can import a list (for example as a .csv file) into Xbox Music?

Comment: Is that an online database or local files?

Comment: currently it's just a set of offline (Excel) files but I could host the data in a database - anything to prevent doing it all manually.

Comment: The music files, I mean.

Comment: right, sorry. I want to stream the songs from Xbox Music using the Xbox Music Pass subscription. I do not have the actual files.